# rendered video is to fast

Tags: rendering, video

when exporting video and then adding the audio. it's not fitting with the video. I can't find an explanation. the video seems to have too much speed. can someone help me with that?.

Comment: Hello and welcome. It is unclear what you are asking. Please use the [edit] link at the 
bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add 
more information on how you set up your project.
[Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that 
might help us understand your scene and settings. See [How to upload 
an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491).

Comment: The video is going too fast and when adding sound it's not fit in the video. who can I render a video with the same speed as the original? obs I'm using a blender to make vhs fx for videos. also, I'm speaking Swedish and not English if someone here can speak Swedish it would be a lot easier for me.

Comment: Are both set to use the same frame rate per second? If the video is rendered you can set the Frame Rate under Output Properties in the R/H properties window.

Comment: thanks worked. how do i render with audio?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbEa_pXH_9E